# Ag-Grid QuickFilter changing programmatically searched columns

Tags: ag-grid

I need a quick search filter, where user can select what columns are searched. I didn't succeed to implement this behavior.
I tried this:

```
this.columns.forEach(column=>{
            if (this.globalSearchSelectedColumns.indexOf(column.field)>-1) column.getQuickFilterText = (params)=> params.value.name;
            else column.getQuickFilterText = ()=> '';
        });
this.grid.api.setColumnDefs(this.columns);
this.grid.api.onFilterChanged();
this.grid.api.resetQuickFilter();
```

where this.columns is columns defs, this.grid is gridOptions, this.globalSearchSelectedColumns is the selected columns to search for, by column.field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to selectively apply `quickFilter` form ag-Grid you should rewrite the property `getQuickFilterText` of the `columnDef`, by setting it to a function which returns an empty string like so:

1. First of all, you need to retrieve the column by a key through the `gridColumnApi`
2. Then you need to access its `colDef`
3. Lastly, all you left to do is to rewrite `getQuickFilterText` property

Assume, that in your class component you have a method `disableFilterCol` it can look something like this:

```
  disableFilterCol = () => {
    var col = this.gridColumnApi.getColumn("athlete");
    var colDef = col.getColDef();
    colDef.getQuickFilterText = () => "";
    console.log("disable Athlete");
  };
```

Once it called, `quickFilter` will be applied to your data grid excluding `athlete` column.

I created [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj2l7m8krq) for you on ReactJS.
You can improve the way you can select multiple columns that you want to rely on doing filtering.

I suppose that in your case you can try to add set `getQuickFilterText = () => ""` for either definition of `colDef` from the very beginning and let the user enabling particular columns, you can set `getQuickFilterText` property for them to undefined to provide sorting among them.

Answer (score 0):

According to nakhodkiin solution I change my code like this:

```
this.grid.columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(column=>{
    let def = column.getColDef();
    if (this.globalSearchSelectedColumns.indexOf(def.field)>-1) def.getQuickFilterText = undefined;
    else def.getQuickFilterText = ()=> '';
});
this.grid.api.onFilterChanged();
```

And it's working;

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here lies in setting updated column defs.
Can you try this -

```
  let newColDef= [];
  this.columns.forEach(column=>{
            if (this.globalSearchSelectedColumns.indexOf(column.field)>-1)
            column.getQuickFilterText = (params)=> params.value.name;
            else column.getQuickFilterText = ()=> '';

            newColDef.push(column);
        });
this.grid.api.setColumnDefs(newColDef);
this.grid.api.onFilterChanged();
this.grid.api.resetQuickFilter();
this.grid.api.refreshHeader();
```

Ag-grid updated its approach of detecting column changes since v19.1
More details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-changes)

As per doc -->

> When new columns are set, the grid will compare with current columns and work out which > columns are old (to be removed), new (new
>   columns created) or kept (columns that remain will keep their state
>   including position, filter and sort).
>
> Comparison of column definitions is done on 1) object reference comparison and 2) 
>   column ID eg colDef.colId. If either the object
>   reference matches, or the column ID matches, then the grid treats the
>   columns as the same column.

Ag-grid team is also actively working on fixing this issue for v20.1. You can track it on [github](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2771)

Comment: This solution is not working, I did't want to vote negative, but by mistake I voted as useful , which is not correct. The only way to delete positive vote was to vote negative. Sorry about that.